# Conditionally choosing screens for auth flow in react navigation v5 not updating

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create my auth flow for a react native application using react navigation v5. Even though I am sure that firebase.auth().currentUser != null is evaluating to true when I sign in and false when I sign out, the page will not change away automatically to the "Closet" page like it says here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#how-it-will-work . I'm certain that I'm signing in correctly because I can print out firebase.auth().currentUser and see if it is null or not.

Why is it not automatically changing pages when I sign in and out? My code is below

Note: I was using isLoggedIn in the conditional instead of firebase.auth().currentUser but neither are working

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import SignIn from '../screens/SignIn';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import firebase from '../config/fbConfig';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => {
 var isLoggedIn = false;

 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if(user){
     console.log("Auth says logged in");
     isLoggedIn = true;
   } else {
     console.log("Auth says logged out");
     isLoggedIn = false;
   }
 })
 
 return ( 
     <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
         {firebase.auth().currentUser != null ? ( 
                 <Stack.Screen name="Closet" component={TabNavigator} />
          ) : (
                 <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignIn} />

          )}

     </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AuthNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because I wasn't using state. I replaced the declaration of isLoggedIn with

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
```